# How to handle single credentials for several applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, architecture, identityserver4

I'm working on multiple projects for single entity, they want the user to have to register just once for all their products (something like Google where you have one Google account for products like Gmail, Drive, YouTube, ... etc.).

My choice for the technology is `Identityserver4` with `ASP.Net Identity` as user credentials store. For this problem I decided to use separate database for `Identityserver` and separate database for `ASP.Net Identity`(*User profile*, *claims*, *credentials*, ... etc.) because, and based on my very humble experience, identity-server is concerned about authentication & authorization but not the mean of storing user data and how to register new users or keeping and maintaining the user data, please correct me if I have a misunderstanding here. I'm not very experienced with `Identityserver` so I think I'm doing huge risk by going with this design. For example, I have audit columns (`CreatedBy`, `UpdatedBy`, `DeletedBy`) in multiple tables in all of these products besides `ownerId` in most of the tables in these databases.

So my question is:

1. How should I reference the user (via `CreatedBy`, `UpdatedBy`, `DeletedBy`, `OwnerId` columns) in the central database in these products databases and should I ever do that (separating the user-store database)?

*And in regards to the user-profile information (user-claims):*

*Those products share many of the information between users like (First name, middle name, last name, address, phone numbers, etc...) and they have other optional info (university, high school) and other that required by some, optional by some, and totally irrelevant by others.*

2. Should I store all these claims in one central table (user-claims
   table in the identity database) and then generate customized profile
   via the `ProfileService` based on the the client (the user
   authenticating to) and the accessToken (what the user allow this
   client to see from it's profile data)?

I hope this question is not an off-topic here in SO and not too-broad.

Answer (score 0):

It was a good decision to build your application with IdentityServer 4 and Identity framework. Because the combination of both has very powerful features (Authentication, Authorization, User management).

As you decided, implement this as one application in your echo system. So now this System works individually for User management, Authentication and Authorization. As an example create users, user groups, user claims, 2FA.... all should be handle in this Application.

Now you can Think above identity server as the third party application (think it as google). So when Login through google it gives us a token that token contains many details depending on what we requested (User ID, Email, Frist name.....).

Okay, now let's think about your second application in the echo system. it doesn't know anything about the users inside the identity server. It only knows the details coming inside the token.

Depending on that token details maintain a separate user table in your second application. you can use Email or userId to keep the mapping of the  Identity server user and new Application user.

For all requirements in the second application use this table to refer the user.